# InitFromXml failed:

Tags: openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect but I'm getting :
InitFromXml failed: The network connection has been closed!

if I do $sudo bash  then I get the following:

InitFromXml failed: Xiron OS got an event timeout!

I'm running Diamondback distribution on Lucid.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10685/initfromxml-failed:/) by [mphielipp](https://answers.ros.org/users/870/mphielipp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity in a month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0